# BUG: insert select edge creates invalid TO references

Tags: orientdb

I suspect this is a serious bug and is raising doubts about how OrientDB manages the integrity of the graphs data during various DML operations.

**How can an Edge have multiple TOs?**

The below outlines a simple operation that is using 'insert into select' to copy a Vertex.

**Initial State**

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#-2:1",
        "@version": 0,
        "rid": "#133:46",
        "version": 1,
        "class": "RuleSet",
        "out_HasRule": [
            "#80:32"
        ],
        "@fieldTypes": "rid=x,out_HasRule=g"
    },
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#-2:2",
        "@version": 0,
        "rid": "#130:39",
        "version": 1,
        "class": "Rule",
        "in_HasRule": [
            "#80:32"
        ],
        "@fieldTypes": "rid=x,in_HasRule=g"
    }
],
"notification": "Query executed  in 0.213 sec. Returned 2 record(s)" }
```

**If I execute the following, bad edge data is created.**
Notice that **#80:32** is the **IN** for more than one Vertex.

```
insert into Rule from select * from #130:39;


{
"result": [
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#-2:1",
        "@version": 0,
        "rid": "#133:46",
        "version": 1,
        "class": "RuleSet",
        "out_HasRule": [
            "#80:32"
        ],
        "@fieldTypes": "rid=x,out_HasRule=g"
    },
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#-2:2",
        "@version": 0,
        "rid": "#131:38",
        "version": 1,
        "class": "Rule",
        "in_HasRule": [
            "#80:32"
        ],
        "@fieldTypes": "rid=x,in_HasRule=g"
    },
    {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#-2:3",
        "@version": 0,
        "rid": "#130:39",
        "version": 1,
        "class": "Rule",
        "in_HasRule": [
            "#80:32"
        ],
        "@fieldTypes": "rid=x,in_HasRule=g"
    }
],
"notification": "Query executed  in 0.151 sec. Returned 3 record(s)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, INSERT/SELECT was designed to copy documents, not vertices, so it also copies edge pointers.

I think it's worth fixig it in one of the two following ways:

- remove the edge links
- also copy the edges

Could you please open an issue here: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues
it will be easier to discuss

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Luigi!

This issue gets at the heart of what we expect from any database, data integrity, so I hope this issue get's to the top of the stack.

Issue has been opened here -> https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/7826

Comment: Quick update, the issue was fixed, it will be released with 2.2.30